# WildMagic 5.9 on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I am trying to build WildMagic 5.9 on Visual Studio 2012 but here are error:

```
Error   3   error C2039: 
'greater' : is not a member of 'std'
c:\wildmagic5\libmathematics\intersection\wm5intrellipsoid3ellipsoid3.cpp 142 1
LibMathematics_VC100
```

Why? What to fix to get this to compile?

Comment: Are you including the `<functional>` header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need include:

```
 include <functional>
```